# Lots of WHEN conditions in CASE statement (binning)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

How can I do binning in SQL Server 2008 if I need about 100 bins? I need to group records depending if a binning variable belongs to one of 100 equal intervals. 
For example if there is continious variable age I could write:

```
CASE
   WHEN AGE >= 0 AND AGE < 1 THEN '1'
   WHEN AGE >= 1 AND AGE < 2 THEN '2'
   ...
   WHEN AGE >= 99 AND AGE < 100 THEN '100'
END [age_group]
```

But this process would be timeconsuming? Are there some other ways how to do that?

Comment: Well - from your example, you don't seem to actually need the CASE as Age of 0 returns 1 and Age of 1 returns 2 and so on.... ? So it seems age_group is just Age + 1?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, that would depend on the datatype of `AGE` (though anything other than `int` would be odd)

Comment: @HoneyBadger indeed, with a different datatype it seems a cast would be possible.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement. (The case expression returns a value.)

Comment: Well, you can always combine this with a table that holds your price segments. You're in a relational database, *use associations*.

Comment: Actually my real task is to do price segmentation:

1.Price of an asset ranges from (0 to 120 000).
2.It's continious variable. 
3.I need to group records if price belongs to one of 100 equal intervals of price.
4. In this case: from 0 to 1 200 would be 1st group. from 1 200 to 2 400 would be 2nd group and so on.

Comment: Could you perhaps use [NTILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175126.aspx)? What you're doing looks like exactly what it was designed for, but it depends on your exact requirements.

Comment: Actually you should post the real task in the question.  You have a lot of wasted answers here.

Comment: My real task was to devide countinious variable which is price of option on group of prices. There were approximately 400 price groups. 

I solved the problem by creating temporary table variable with boundaries of each group and the number of these groups as records. I filled this table using Excel. Then I joined the temporary table with original table on condition: boundary1<= price < boundary2. 
That gave me what I want: 400 groups that are very is to create.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: That method worked well, because I could manually with Excel customize large amount of groups very quickly

Comment: @YuryMorozov more to the point did any of the answers answer the question you asked, if so you should accept one of them, Even if they don't answer the question that you wished you'd asked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this based upon your comment about the segments being 1200:

```
;With Number
AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM (Values(1),(2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10))N(x)
),
Segments
As
( 
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Num1.x) -1) * 1200 As StartNum,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Num1.x)  * 1200 As EndNum 
    FROM Number Num1
    CROSS APPLY Number Num2
)
SELECT *
FROM Segments
    SELECT *
    FROM Segments
    INNER JOIN MyTable
       ON MyTable.Price >= StartNum AND MyTable.Price < EndNum
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code Once:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN AGE = 0 THEN 1
         ELSE Ceiling([age])
       END [age_group]
FROM   @T
```

Here CEILING function returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to the specified numeric expression.i.e select CEILING(0.1) SQL Returns 1 As Output

But According to Your Output Requirement Floor(age)+1 is enough to get Required Output.

```
SELECT Floor([age]) + 1 [age_group]
    FROM   @T
```

Here Floor Function Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified numeric expression.

Comment: @Allan S. Hansen Yes FLOOR(age)+1 Also Works. But Why We need to do again +1 fro that FLOOR function instead of that CEILING Returns Direct answer.

Comment: Agree with @AllanS.Hansen; since the condition `1 <= x < 2` gives 2 you'd need his version.  Ajay's version works best were the condition `1 < x <= 2` (which is the more common scenario).  This also alleviates the need for the case statement (unless you also wish to check for `x < 0` and `x >= 100` for exception handling).

Comment: But OP wants 1 to return 2.  This does not

Comment: @Frisbee Yes Ceiling Not produce the Required Output in this case but Floor(age)+1 Produce Required Output.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics, I guess. In this case,

```
Ceiling(Age) AS [age_group]
```

cast as necessary into character type of your choice. Ceiling is the 'round up to an integer' function in SQL Server.

Comment: When Age is zero, this returns 0, but OP needs '1' ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use arithmetic for this purpose.  Something like this:

```
select floor(bins * (age - minage) / (range + 1)), count(*)
from t cross join
     (select min(age) as minage, max(age) as maxage,
             1.0*(max(age) - min(age)) as range, 100 as bins
      from t
     ) m
group by floor(bins * (age - minage) / (range + 1))
```

However, this is overkill for your example, which doesn't need a `case` at all.

Comment: Your answer actually lead me to solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your interval for the groups are fixed - for example 1200, you can just do an integer division to get the index with that grouping.

For example:

`SELECT 1000 / 1200` equals 0
`SELECT 2200 / 1200` equals 1
Remember - you need to cast to int to get the result if you're using a decimal datatype. Integer division requires int on both sides of the operator.

And then add 1 to get the group